# ¿Cómo mostrar solo una vez un alert en un ciclo for JS?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Estoy haciendo la inserción a dos tablas `SQL` de las filas de una tabla HTML. Obtengo los datos de las filas con un ciclo `for` y dentro del ciclo tengo dos funciones `ajax` que envían los datos a la página que procesa la inserción a mi BD. En el método success invoco a un `alert` para que me muestre un mensaje cuando se haya insertado el registro correctamente. El problema es que cada que inserta una fila de la tabla HTML me aparece el `alert` y es lógico porque está dentro del ciclo for.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que me aparezca solo una vez el `alert` del `ajax` y no tantas veces como registros se inserten en la BD?

```js
    $("#btnGenerarNomina").click(function() {
          var tabla = document.getElementById("tblNomina");
          var c1 = tabla.getElementsByClassName("numSolicitud");
          var c2 = tabla.getElementsByClassName("numVendedor");
          var c3 = tabla.getElementsByClassName("nombreEmpleado");
          var c4 = tabla.getElementsByClassName("numEmpleado");
          var c5 = tabla.getElementsByClassName("telActivacion");
          var c6 = tabla.getElementsByClassName("fechaActivacion");
          var c7 = tabla.getElementsByClassName("planRenta");
          var c8 = tabla.getElementsByClassName("tramite");
          var c9 = tabla.getElementsByClassName("plazo");
          var c10 = tabla.getElementsByClassName("fechaEntrega");
          var c11 = tabla.getElementsByClassName("diasTranscurridos");
          var c12 = tabla.getElementsByClassName("comision");

          for (var i = 0; i < c1.length; i++) {
            var solicitud = c1[i].innerHTML;
            var numVendedor = c2[i].innerHTML;
            var nombre = c3[i].innerHTML;
            var comision = c12[i].innerHTML;
            var datosFormulario = {
              numSolicitud: solicitud.trim(),
              numVendedor: numVendedor.trim(),
              nombreEmpleado: nombre.trim(),
              valorComision: comision.trim()
            };
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "procesaGenerar",
              data: datosFormulario,
              success: function(data) {

                var ress = data;


                if (i = c1.length) {
                  alert(i + "actualiza");
                  alert(ress);
                }

              }
            });

            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "procesaGuardaComisionesPospago",
              data: datosFormulario,
              success: function(resultado) {
                //alert(resultado);
                var res = resultado;
                //if (res.trim() == "Guardado éxitoso") {
                alert(i + "guarda");
                if (i < 1) {
                  alert(i + "guarda");
                  alert(res);
                  myFunction("atencionNegocios");
                }
                //}
              }
            });
          }
```

Intenté meter una condición `if` en los resultados que devuelve el ajax, pero no funcionó.

Comment: `if (i = c1.length) { }` debería ser `if (i == c1.length) { }`

Comment: @aldanux y el segundo ajax realiza la insercion pero no muestra ningun mensaje debo corregir algo?

Comment: El problema es que el contador `i` jamas sera == a `cl.lenght` ya que la condicion de tu for es que sea menor.

Comment: @sioesi como podria resolver la condicion por que tambien coloque que if (i< 1){...} pero tampoco funciono

Comment: Lo que no entiendo es algo : quieres 1 alert en la ultima iteracion y tambien en la primera?

Comment: @sioesi no lo que quiero es que aparezca una sola ves el alert del primer ajax y una sola vez el alert del segundo ajax ya que si tengo 10 filas en la tabla HTML me aparece 10 veces el mesaje de cada una de las funciones ajax,  la condicion del if (i<1) fue una prueba pero no funciono

Answer (score 3):

Eso lo solucionas con una bandera.

```
band = false
 for (var i = 0; i < c1.length; i++) {
      // tu codigo aqui 
      if(!band){
         alert("tu comentario en el alert")
         band = true
      }
 }
```

De esa forma, solo imprimirá el alert una vez. Ahora, lo que no estoy muy convendido es que envies tantas peticiones con ajax. ¿No seria mejor que obtengas toda la data y hagas un solo envio?

Saludos.

Comment: no se como obtener toda la data

Comment: @Ivxn este if lo introduces en tu función de `success`.

Answer (score 2):

Supongo que la idea es enviar el `alert` en el último "paso" del ciclo.

```
if(i == c1.length-1){
alert('Lo que quieras alertar');
}
```

Comment: Esta debería ser la respuesta. Es obviamente la más simple.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que te recomiendo es encapsular en una función cada llamado de ajax, con esto conseguimos que cada llamado al ajax tenga un valor fijo enviado por parametro `i` que es el contador de tu ciclo `for`. Me parece que dentro de el llamado `ajax` el valor `i` no cambia

```
var c1, c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10,c11,c12;

$("#btnGenerarNomina").click(function() {

var tabla = document.getElementById("tblNomina");
c1 = tabla.getElementsByClassName("numSolicitud");
c2 = tabla.getElementsByClassName("numVendedor");
c3 = tabla.getElementsByClassName("nombreEmpleado");
c4 = tabla.getElementsByClassName("numEmpleado");
c5 = tabla.getElementsByClassName("telActivacion");
c6 = tabla.getElementsByClassName("fechaActivacion");
c7 = tabla.getElementsByClassName("planRenta");
c8 = tabla.getElementsByClassName("tramite");
c9 = tabla.getElementsByClassName("plazo");
c10 = tabla.getElementsByClassName("fechaEntrega");
c11 = tabla.getElementsByClassName("diasTranscurridos");
c12 = tabla.getElementsByClassName("comision");

for (var i = 0; i < c1.length; i++) {
    guardar1(i);
    guardar2(i);
}

});

function guardar1(i){
    var solicitud = c1[i].innerHTML;
    var numVendedor = c2[i].innerHTML;
    var nombre = c3[i].innerHTML;
    var comision = c12[i].innerHTML;
    var datosFormulario = {
          numSolicitud: solicitud.trim(),
          numVendedor: numVendedor.trim(),
          nombreEmpleado: nombre.trim(),
          valorComision: comision.trim()
        };
    $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "procesaGenerar",
          data: datosFormulario,
          success: function(data) {

            var ress = data;


            if ((i+1) == c1.lenght) {
              alert(i + "actualiza");
              alert(ress);
            }
          }
     });
}

function guardar2(i){
    var solicitud = c1[i].innerHTML;
    var numVendedor = c2[i].innerHTML;
    var nombre = c3[i].innerHTML;
    var comision = c12[i].innerHTML;
    var datosFormulario = {
      numSolicitud: solicitud.trim(),
      numVendedor: numVendedor.trim(),
      nombreEmpleado: nombre.trim(),
      valorComision: comision.trim()
    };
    $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "procesaGuardaComisionesPospago",
          data: datosFormulario,
          success: function(resultado) {
            //alert(resultado);
            var res = resultado;
            //if (res.trim() == "Guardado éxitoso") {
            alert(i + "guarda");
            if (i == 0) {
              alert(i + "guarda");
              alert(res);
              myFunction("atencionNegocios");
            }
            //}
          }
    });
}
```

**EDIT**

El operador `=` es de asignacion mientras que `==` es de comparación.

Comment: de la forma que me indicas en el primer caso lo hice asi y ya me genero solo un alert y la insercion la hace bien, lo quise implementar en el segundo caso con la misma condicion if, pero no me muestra nada en el segundo if, pero si realiza la insercion

Comment: Puedes imprimir el valor de `i` en el segundo ajax?

Comment: como tengo 6 filas en mi tabla HTML si me trae el valor i y es 6

Comment: Pero i es un contador dentro de tu ciclo por lo tanto imprimelo y te deberia dar 0....5

Comment: solo me imprime el 6 las 6 veces

Comment: Extraño que te imprima siempre 6 cuando es un contador dentro de tu ciclo... puedes comentar todo lo que esta dentro de tu for e imprimir solo el valor de i? alert(i);

Comment: comente todo y solo imprimi la variable i y me genera los valores 0,1.. 5, pero ahora cuando imprimo el valor de i desde dentro del success de la funcion ajax solo me imprime el valor 6, uso Google Chrome y firefox

Comment: Voy a editar mi respuesta

Comment: @Ivxn ya la actualice

Comment: me genera un error en c1 is not defined de la funcion guarda1()

Comment: Lo actualice y envio el valor por parametro

Comment: Cambio el codigo en el for y la funcion le agregue otro parametro

Comment: Se me fue un detalle! @Ivxn ahora si que si sorry